# Tokenized string of char to ints using atoi

Tags: c, char, token, tokenize, atoi

I am trying to take user input: (1 345 44 23) and make it into a tokenized char string then into ints. Surprisingly I could not find much help for what I would think would be a common task.

Any ideas how to convert the char string into an in string using tokens?

My program crashes when it gets to the conversion (after the tokenization [I realize this is not a word]).

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#define StrSZE 81


void strInput (char str[], int maxChars);
void custatoi(char * tokenArray[], int * data, int numOfTok);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[StrSZE];
    char* tokenArray;
    int maxChars=StrSZE-1, cont=1, numOfToken=0, i=0;
    int* data;


    strInput(str, maxChars);


    tokenArray = strtok(str, " \t");
    while (tokenArray)
    {
        printf("token: %s\n", tokenArray);
        tokenArray = strtok(NULL, " \t");
        numOfToken++;
    }


    data = (int *) malloc(numOfToken * sizeof(int));

    custatoi(tokenArray, data, numOfToken);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}



void strInput (char str[], int maxChars)
{
    char garbage;
    int k=0;

    str[0]='\0';

    printf("Please type a string of whole numbers (intigers).\n\n");

    while ((k<80) && ((str[k] = getchar()) != '\n'))
        k++;

    /* Clears the keyboard buffer.  */
    if (k==80)
        while((garbage = getchar()) != '\n')
            ;

    /* Place null at the end of the line read in from user */
    str[k]='\0';

    printf("str after input is: %s\n\n", str);
}


void custatoi(char * tokenArray[], int * data, int numOfTok)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < numOfTok; i++)
        data[i] = atoi(tokenArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I corrected the errors in yours code:  There was some `mistakes in main(), tokenArray data type was not correct.`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#define StrSZE 81


void strInput (char str[], int maxChars);
void custatoi(char*  tokenArray[], int * data, int numOfTok);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[StrSZE];


    int maxChars=StrSZE-1, cont=1, numOfToken=0, i=0;
    int* data;
    char* tokenArray[50];    // Declared correctly 

    strInput(str, maxChars);


    tokenArray[i] = strtok(str, " \t");   // Also made a change here!
    while (tokenArray[i])
    {
        printf("token: %s\n", tokenArray[i]);
        i++;
        tokenArray[i] = strtok(NULL, " \t");
        numOfToken++;
    }


    data = (int *) malloc(numOfToken * sizeof(int));

    custatoi(tokenArray, data, numOfToken);

    printf("data\n");
    for(i=0;i<numOfToken;i++){
        printf(" %d\n",data[i]);

    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}



void strInput (char str[], int maxChars)
{
    char garbage;
    int k=0;

    str[0]='\0';

    printf("Please type a string of whole numbers (intigers).\n\n");

    while ((k<80) && ((str[k] = getchar()) != '\n'))
        k++;

    /* Clears the keyboard buffer.  */
    if (k==80)
        while((garbage = getchar()) != '\n')
            ;

    /* Place null at the end of the line read in from user */
    str[k]='\0';

    printf("str after input is: %s\n\n", str);
}


void custatoi(char*  tokenArray[], int * data, int numOfTok)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < numOfTok; i++)
        data[i] = atoi(tokenArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! ...What were the mistakes?

Comment: you declared 'tokenArray' as char* but it has to be char* tokenArray[] type.

Comment: also Answered by Mr. Alexey Frunze.

Comment: thanks for the friendly reminder :) And thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the `strtok` loop, `tokenArray` will be set to `NULL`. You then pass it to `custatoi`, which presumably crashes when it tries to dereference it.

Note that `tokenArray` is not an array of strings; it's just a single string pointer (or a pointer to an array of characters). If you want to accumulate the tokens into an array, you'll have to create a separate array for that purpose.

Comment: So because 'tokenArray' is a string pointer, shouldn't I be able to use it like I am in 'custatoi' to make an seperate array of ints?

Comment: Well, the first problem is that you pass `NULL` instead of a valid string. The second problem is that a string pointer (`char *`) can only point to a single string -- it cannot meaningfully represent an array of strings (that would be `char **` or `char *[]`). In your case, you are basically casting `char *` to `char *[]`, which is a big no-no.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that `custatoi()` expects to work with an array of pointers to `char`, while `tokenArray` in `main()` is a mere pointer to `char`. The original code never collects all pointers to tokens in the input string into an array that `custatoi()` expects, there isn't such an array in the original code.

Please study the fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define StrSZE 81

void custatoi(char* tokenArray[], int* data, int numOfTok);

int main(void)
{
    char str[StrSZE];
    char** tokenArray;
    int numOfToken = 0, i;
    int* data;

    //strInput(str, maxChars);
    strcpy(str, "1 345 44 23");

    tokenArray = malloc(sizeof(char*));

    tokenArray[numOfToken] = strtok(str, " \t");
    while (tokenArray[numOfToken] != NULL)
    {
        printf("token: %s\n", tokenArray[numOfToken]);
        numOfToken++;
        tokenArray = realloc(tokenArray, sizeof(char*) * (numOfToken + 1));
        tokenArray[numOfToken] = strtok(NULL, " \t");
    }

    data = malloc(numOfToken * sizeof(int));

    custatoi(tokenArray, data, numOfToken);

    for (i = 0; i < numOfToken; i++)
      printf("data[%d]=%d\n", i, data[i]);

    return 0;
}

void custatoi(char* tokenArray[], int* data, int numOfTok)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < numOfTok; i++)
        data[i] = atoi(tokenArray[i]);
}
```

Output ([idone](http://ideone.com/XBI3bY)):

```
token: 1
token: 345
token: 44
token: 23
data[0]=1
data[1]=345
data[2]=44
data[3]=23
```

Comment: This provides much insight. Thank you!